# Calculate $\int_{x^2+y^2+z^2<x+y+z} (x^2+y^2+z^2)dxdydz$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, substitution

> Calculate the integral: $$\int_{x^2+y^2+z^2<x+y+z} (x^2+y^2+z^2)dxdydz$$

Of course calculating the integral $\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}\int_{e}^{f} (x^2+y^2+z^2)dxdydz$ would be very easy. However I have a problem because I must find $a,b,c,d,e,f$. I tried to use substitution: $$\begin{cases} x=r \cos \alpha \cos \beta \\ y=r \cos \beta \sin \alpha \\ z=r \sin \beta \end{cases} \text{   or   } \begin{cases} x=r \cos \alpha \\ y=r  \sin \alpha \\ z=z \end{cases}$$
But every of them proved to be ineffective.

Is there anyone who have some tips what I can do to find limits of integrity?

Comment: It is basic courtesy in this site to accept and upvote answers. That is the only way you reward users who took time to answer your query. You have not done so in most of your questions.

Answer (score 5):

Note that \begin{align*} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < x+y+z \,\,\,\,\, &\Longleftrightarrow \,\,\,\,\, (x^2-x) + (y^2-y) + (z^2-z) < 0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \,\,\,\,\, (x-1/2)^2 + (y-1/2)^2 + (z-1/2)^2 < 3/4.
\end{align*} Thus you are integrating over a sphere centered not at the origin, but at $(1/2,1/2,1/2)$ which should inform your substitution.

Comment: "over a sphere centered not at the origin, but at  $(1/2,1/2,1/2)$ - do you mean $x=r \cos \alpha \cos \beta +\frac{1}{2}, y=r \cos \beta \sin \alpha + \frac{1}{2},  z=r \sin \beta + \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @timofiej8384 yes that would be right (adding the $1/2$ I mean... I didn't carefully verify if you have the correct trig, because that's not the form of spherical coordinates I remember, but it looks fine). Now, just be sure to set up the bounds of integration for $r$ carefully (don't forget any squares/square roots)

Comment: My bounds: $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}>r\ge 0, \alpha \in (-\pi,\pi), \beta \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ . Is it correct?